# Data array for jQuery AJAX success

Tags: jquery, ajax

On server I am returning an array after some operations. I want to work with this array after the Ajax call succeeds.

```
var addPaymentType = function(){
    var data = new Object()
    data["function"]        = "add";
    data["payment_type_id"] = $("#payment_types").val();
    data["data"]            = $("#saveform").serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: location.href,
        data: data,
        dataType: "JSON",
        success : function (data)
        {
            console.debug(data['plan_pt_id']);
        }
    });
};
```

But `data['plan_pt_id']` is `undefined`. If I return not an array, all works pretty. But how can I work with array?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lowercase "json" and data['plan_pt_id'],data['descr']

Comment: data['plan_pt_id'] won't work if data is an array. Perhaps you mean PHP associative array? In javascript, that's an object.

Comment: Yes. It is associative array. I didn't know that it is an object in JS.

Answer (score 2):

If data is an array, then you access it with e.g.

```
data[0]
```

If the first object in your array has a 'plan_pt_id' property, then you can access that with:

```
data[0].plan_pt_id
```

or with

```
data[0]['plan_pt_id']
```

The next object would be `data[1]`, etc.

Comment: data[0] returns "{". Others return "undefined". My dataType is JSON. Maybe problem in it?

Comment: data[0] returns 'undefined' instead of "{"(Pichalka